# Does an activated carbon filter in a kitchen hood dry the air?

Tags: equipment

Clearly, an activated carbon filter can be expected to collect what comes from the cooking plate with the air. But what happens to the moisture, how much of it what gets sucked into the hood with the air will also leave the hood?

(if it heavily depends on the model, its Juno JDK4575E and let's take not fried egg but say cooking noodles).

Answer (score 2):

I assume the moisture/vapour gets sucked in by the vent and eventually condensate (sp?) at some point in the duct and then evaporate normally.

Comment: Carbon is a bit hydrophobic, so I would not expect much to get bound to the filter.

Comment: The comment above is the answer. Fine details would be chemistry rather than kitchen. Active carbon is used in water treatment too. As such its interaction with water must be quite negligible as compared to that with plenty of molecules else it wouldn't even "see" them when present as contaminants in water plans, for instance. The answer itself is correct too. The assumption is right :)